# Microsoft Symbol Server for .NET - problem

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've configured Visual Studio to use Microsoft Symbol Server and it downloaded PDB for System.dll, and then loaded it successfully, but there is no any source code files - only PDB. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plz don't consider this as advertisement ;) But this task can be solved with Reflector 7 Pro. It allows to debug FCL assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

the symbols are not source code... if you want to debug with framework source see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: Odd downvote, this answer is correct.  Getting the Reference source to work is a challenge, it was borked again after the VS2010 SP1 update with a vague promise that the required source update was coming soon.  Be sure to empty the symbols cache.

Comment: So, it doesn't work with VS2010 SP1? Ughm, I "love" Microsoft so much.